# Cannot read property 'object' of undefined - react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom 4.0.0. I have the following code

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const About = () => (
    <div>
        <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
);

const Home = () => (
    <div>
        <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
);



const BasicExample = () => (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
            </ul>

            <hr />

            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </div>
    </Router>
);

render(<BasicExample />, document.body);
```

The issue here is I am getting the error of property string undefined.

> VM1542 bundle.js:3589 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'object' of undefined

Any help would be appreciated here. Thanks

Comment: It is working for me with a copy/paste.

Comment: Worked for me too. Can you add the line which throws this error..

Answer (score 0):

I guess this problem related to the `react-router-dom` version 4.0.0 , so you need to upgrade to the latest version.

```
npm install react-router-dom@* --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch the '/' route with the '/about' route. The rendering will look for about component first if not found will god for the home component